# static member definition outside class template template

Tags: c++, definition, static-members, template-templates

I'm getting:

```
error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'ticker<T, E, A>::garbage_element'
   51 | E ticker<T,E,A> ::garbage_element;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

l know if I use the keyword "inline" like this:

```
    inline static  E garbage_element;
```

inside the "ticker" template, it compiles fine,
but how in the world it suppose to look like outside the template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template< template<class, class> class T, class E, class A = std::allocator<E>  >
class ticker
{
    T<E,A>* container;
    int current_index;
    bool mode;
    static  E garbage_element;
 public:
    // constructors and members fn
};

template< template<class, class> class T, class E, class A = std::allocator<E> >
E ticker<T,E,A> ::garbage_element;
```

Comment: Well, did you try doing what the error message says: get rid of the default argument?

Comment: i wish the message was more clear like: 'default argument not allowed here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the static data member of a class template which has a default argument for one of its template parameter, the default argument should not be repeated. It is **needed only once** when the class template is first declared/defined.

This means you don't need to specify the default argument for parameter `A` when defining the member `garbage_element` outside the class as shown below:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------v-->no default argument here
template<template<class, class> class T, class E, class A>
E ticker<T,E,A>::garbage_element;
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d87f83sqa)

Comment: thanks for clearing the error message

Comment: one more quesion if you dont mind, i have function find(me,here):            
template< template<class, class> class T, class E, class A = std::allocator<E>  >
bool find(ticker< T,E,A >& me, ticker< T,E,A >& here) {//...}            the compiler did not complain about the default agument here, why?

Comment: @AmmarTamimi Looking at your last comment, `find` looks like a nonmember function so default argument can be used there.

Comment: I think I got it! so basically when you define member outside class template: static members, constructors, member fns, must not have redefintion of default arguments even if it is exactly the same. correct?

Comment: @AmmarTamimi Yes exactly, only for "members" you must not repeat the default argument.  You're welcome.